# Single tap not workig in radio field

Tags: radio-button, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to generate an event on checking the radio field. The field is checked on a single tap but the event is generated only when i double tap on it.

Anything that am doing wrong. This is the code that I have used.

```
{
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            //  ui:'plain',
            id : 'r1',
            name : 'sendDoc',
            value : 'Default',
            label : 'Default',
            labelWidth : '50%',
            checked : true,
            //baseCls: 'x-plain',

            listeners : {
                check: function ( radioFld, event, opts ){
                    if(radioFld.isChecked()){
                        Ext.getCmp('workstep').disable();
                    }
                }

            }
        }, 
        {
            xtype : 'radiofield',
            name : 'sendDoc',
            id : 'r2',
            value : 'Source Workstep',
            label : 'Source Workstep',
            labelWidth : '50%',
            listeners : {
                check : function(radioFld, event, opts ) {
                    console.log(radioFld.isChecked());
                        if (radioFld.isChecked())   {
                            Ext.getCmp('workstep').enable();
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but if you look at this fiddle:
http://www.senchafiddle.com/#EiQID#UTcRj#bTsT0,

you'll see that the events 'check' and 'uncheck' are triggered correctly when changing the selection from the first radiofield to the second and vice-versa, using a single tap.

Is that working for you?
If not, what is happening exactly?

Comment: well..it works the same way. When i check it the first time, it only gets checked. i dont get the console. the second time i check it(when its already checked) it generates the event.

Comment: hmm... that's weird! I tested it on Desktop(Chrome,Safari), iPhone and iPad and it's working perfectly on all those browsers... Which device are you testing this code on?

Comment: i checked it on chrome. It worked fine after i generated an uncheck event and did the same action there.